# Xgboost: what is the difference among bst.best_score, bst.best_iteration and bst.best_ntree_limit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

When I use xgboost to train my data for a `2-cates classification problem`,I'd like to use the early stopping to get the best model, but I'm confused about which one to use in my predict as the early stop will return 3 different choices.
For example, should I use

```
preds = model.predict(xgtest, ntree_limit=bst.best_iteration)
```

or should I use

```
preds = model.predict(xgtest, ntree_limit=bst.best_ntree_limit)
```

or both right, and they should be applied to different circumstances? If so, how can I judge which one to use?

Here is the original quotation of the xgboost document, but it didn't  give the reason why and I also didn't find the comparison between those params:

> Early Stopping
>
> If you have a validation set, you can use early stopping to find the
>   optimal number of boosting rounds. Early stopping requires at least
>   one set in evals. If there's more than one, it will use the last.
>
> train(..., evals=evals, early_stopping_rounds=10)
>
> The model will train until the validation score stops improving.
>   Validation error needs to decrease at least every
>   early_stopping_rounds to continue training.
>
> If early stopping occurs, the model will have three additional fields:
>   bst.best_score, bst.best_iteration and bst.best_ntree_limit. Note that
>   train() will return a model from the last iteration, not the best one.
>   Pr
>   ediction
>
> A model that has been trained or loaded can perform predictions on
>   data sets.
>
> ```
> # 7 entities, each contains 10 features 
> data = np.random.rand(7, 10) 
> dtest = xgb.DMatrix(data) 
> ypred = bst.predict(dtest)
> ```
>
> If early stopping
>   is enabled during training, you can get predictions from the best
>   iteration with bst.best_ntree_limit:
>
> `ypred = bst.predict(dtest,ntree_limit=bst.best_ntree_limit)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering this same thing. In a few tests that I've run, `bst.best_iteration` seems to be just 1 lower than `bst.best_ntree_limit`. My thinking is that `bst.best_iteration` gives you the number of the best one, but then you want to set the limit to 1 higher (so that it gets to the best one before it hits the limit). This seems a bit silly and simplistic though. Hence, I am still wondering... Have you noticed the same thing?

Comment: @seth127, well, that is not true, actually, `bst.best_iteration seems to be just 1 lower than bst.best_ntree_limit` may be caused by the iteration you set, you can try to set the iterations higher.

Comment: In my understanding, `best_ntree_limit` gives you the total number of trees, but `best_iteration` gives you the iteration *number*, which is one lower possibly because the iteration number starts from zero.

Comment: Surprised that this question still doesn't have a good answer, or any clarification in the documentation yet!

Comment: The documentation lacks a clear explanation on this, but it seems : 
`best_iteration` is the best iteration, starting at 0. `best_ntree_limit`is the best number of trees. By default, it should be equal to `best_iteration`+1, since iteration 0 has 1 tree, iteration 1 has 2 trees and so on. BUT, you can define `num_parallel_tree`, which allow for multiples trees growing at each iterations.  `best_score` should be the score ate the best n_tree, but it's unclear how it works with `num_parallel_tree`>1, since eval is not done after every trees is build.

Comment: My conclusion is : do not use `num_parallel_tree` (it defeats the whole boosting purpose anyway), and use `ntree_limit=bst.best_ntree_limit`

Answer (score 6):

In my point of view, both parameters refer to the same think, or at least have the same goal. But I would rather use:

```
preds = model.predict(xgtest, ntree_limit=bst.best_iteration)
```

From the source code, we can see [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/663136aa08c00598d8b49adf5901e4cb2ce187da/python-package/xgboost/core.py#L1142) that `best_ntree_limit` is going to be dropped in favor of `best_iteration`.

```
def _get_booster_layer_trees(model: "Booster") -> Tuple[int, int]:
    """Get number of trees added to booster per-iteration.  This function will be removed
    once `best_ntree_limit` is dropped in favor of `best_iteration`.  Returns
    `num_parallel_tree` and `num_groups`.
    """
```

Additionally, `best_ntree_limit` has been removed from [EarlyStopping](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html#early-stopping) documentation page.

So I think this attribute exist only for backwards compatibility reasons. From this code snippet and the documentation, we can therefore assume that `best_ntree_limit` is or will be deprecated.